# Not understanding d3 v4 new general update pattern in nested data

Tags: d3.js

I've used previous versions of D3 and coming back at v4 I've encountered I don't quite grasp the new update pattern. I have nested data and I wish to update my visualization with new child nodes, here is a minimum example:

```
function update(data) {
  var rows = d3
    .selectAll("div")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("div")
      .classed("row", true)

   var cells = rows
      .selectAll("div")
      .data(function(d) { return d })

  cells
      .enter()
      .append("div")
      .classed("cell", true)
      .text(function(d) {return d})
 }

var arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3]
]

var button = d3.select("body")
  .append("button")
  .text("update")
  .on("click", modifyData);

function modifyData(){
  arr.forEach(row => {
    row.push(4)
  });
  update(arr);
}

update(arr);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/59qnhb8d/

I would expect my viz to update with a column of 4's. Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to update and MERGE the new divs with the old divs:

```
function update(data) {
  var rows = d3
    .selectAll(".row")
      .data(data)

  rows.exit().remove();

  var newRows = rows.enter()
      .append("div")
      .classed("row", true)

  var cells = rows.merge(newRows) //here you tell it to merge new rows with existing rows
      .selectAll(".cell")
      .data(function(d) { console.log(d); return d })

  cells.exit().remove();

  var newCells = cells  
      .enter()
      .append("div")
      .classed("cell", true)

   cells
        .merge(newCells)
      .text(function(d) {return d})
 }
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/59qnhb8d/31/

Comment: I like the style of this code better than the answer from pmkro, but I think pmkro's answer is more complete.  It references the exit to remove old elements.  If you combine the two, it works better :)

Answer (score 4):

A few things have likely changed [here is Mike Bostocks General Update Pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234). Here is a fiddle with a working update [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8ut9j5e/15/). There are 4 important steps in the update pattern:

1) Binding the new data

2) Removing nodes no longer needed

3) Merging non-removed nodes with the newly created ones

4) Updating nodes.

The change is in the update function, the updated version is below.

I went with the `.each` method for each row created to have better control over the nesting, and without having to do any modifications to the data object. The `.each` method uses the same pattern, just on its own nested nodes.

```
function update(data) {
    var rows = d3.select("body").selectAll(".row").data(data); // bind data
  rows.exit().remove();                                        // remove old nodes
  rows.enter().append("div")                                   // add new nodes
    .classed("row", true)
    .merge(rows)       // merge new with existing and update all
    .each(function(d){
        let el = d3.select(this);
        let cells = el.selectAll(".cell").data(d); // bind data
        cells.exit().remove();                     //remove old
        cells.enter().append("div")                //enter new
          .classed("cell", true)
          .merge(cells)                            //merge
          .text(d=>d)                              // set text on all nodes.
    });
}
```

Comment: @RyanMorton oops thanks, forgot to update after some changes.